# Android Wear - Not able to type with keyword

Tags: wear-os

While creating AVD for Wear the [Getting Started Guide](http://developer.android.com/wear/preview/start.html) mentions following.

> Although real Android wearables do not provide a keyboard as an input
>   method, you should keep Hardware keyboard present selected so you can
>   provide text input on screens where users will instead provide voice
>   input.

[image]

I'm able to pair android phone with wear AVD and swipe through the notification on wear emulator. But not able to use keyboard to type replies for actions like - Gmail's reply.

What is the issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the Gmail app wasn't built for AndroidWear it might not be possible to answer using the emulator.

Using the ElizaChat sample application (included in the preview) it is possible to use the HW keyboard for replies... (Tested)

You can see more details on how to implement on your app here:
http://developer.android.com/wear/notifications/remote-input.html

Answer (score 0):

As the notice suggests, be sure you have "hardware keyboard present" checked on your AVD configuration. The presence of a hardware keyboard and running in an emulator will trigger the support for "fake" speech input in the preview release.

[image]

Comment: hi mark, i have this option checked. still not able to get it working. the picture i attached comes up all the time.